# Color Gradient between block and blocktitle leave a white line

Tags: beamer, spacing

[image]![The color gradient between the block title and block body in beamer leaves a small white line to the far left of where the color-gradient bar used to be 
I used these four lines at the beginning of my page to make more visible.

```
\useinnertheme{rounded} 
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareverticalshading[lower.bg,upper.bg]{bmb@transition}{-1cm}{color(0pt)=(white_pink); color(0pt)=(white_pink); color(2.7pt)=(white_pink)}
\makeatother
```

I can remove the distance between the block, but the small white line at the left on block remains. 
How do I remove this little white line on left between the block-title and the block-body?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.